# [Errno 13]:Permission Denied when trying to edit the hosts file with a script in .ps1, in .py and in .bat. Hosts file with full permission to edit

Tags: python, windows, powershell, hosts, hosts-file

I want to edit the hosts file with a script that will run from the Windows Task Scheduler, but even granting elevated permissions to this script, when it tries to edit the hosts file, access is denied `([Errno 13]:Permission Denied)`.
I created a script in PowerShell (ps1), in Python (py) and a .bat script and they all give access denied.

---

But when I run the ps1 script in PowerShell ISE as administrator it can edit the hosts file. When I run the python script in Pycharm in **Debug** mode it can edit the hosts file.

````
POWERSHELL:
$bloqueado = $false

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Write-Host (Get-ExecutionPolicy)

$caminhoHosts = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
Add-Content -Path $caminhoHosts -Value "teste"

while ($true) {
    # Get a list of active RDP sessions
    $rdpSessions = quser | Where-Object { $_ -match 'rdp' }

    if ($rdpSessions) {
        if (-not $bloqueado) {
            Write-Host "VPN LIGADA"

            $textoAdicional1 = "127.0.0.1    x."
            $textoAdicional3 = "127.0.0.1    xx"
            $textoAdicional5 = "127.0.0.1    xxx"
            $textoAdicional6 = "127.0.0.1    xxxx"

            Add-Content -Path $caminhoHosts -Value "$textoAdicional1`r`n$textoAdicional3`r`n$textoAdicional5`r`n$textoAdicional6"

            $nomesNavegadores = @("chrome", "firefox", "iexplore", "msedge", "opera")
            foreach ($nome in $nomesNavegadores) {
                Stop-Process -Name $nome -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }

            $bloqueado = $true
        }
    }

    else {
        Write-Host "VPN DESLIGADA"

        if ($bloqueado) {
            $linhas = Get-Content -Path $caminhoHosts

            foreach ($indiceLinha in 0..($linhas.Count - 1)) {
                $linha = $linhas[$indiceLinha]
                if ($linha -match "x|x|x") {
                    $linhas = $linhas | Where-Object { $_ -ne $linha }
                }
                elseif($linha -match "x|x|x"){
                    $linhas = $linhas | Where-Object { $_ -ne $linha }
                }
            }

            $linhas | Set-Content -Path $caminhoHosts

            $bloqueado = $false
        }
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}```
````

Python:

````
hosts_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

with open(hosts_path, "a") as hosts_file:
    hosts_file.write(f"\n127.0.0.1 eae.com") ```
````

- I've already changed the permissions on the hosts file, so everything is now clear.
- I've already edited the PowerShell execution policy to "Unrestricted" and "Bypass", but also without success.
- I have already created an executable with the PowerShell and Python script, but it also gives access to hosts denied.
- In the task scheduler the task is to run with higher privileges.
- I disabled Windows UAC too.

Comment: Tell us more about how you configured the scheduled task - which account did you configure as the logon account, and what did you set as the starting/working directory for the trigger?

Comment: Action:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments:
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Serviço Windows.ps1"

Comment: That's not what I asked about. Which account did you configure as the logon account? `Get-ScheduledTask 'Name of task' |% Principal` will show you

Comment: I created it with an account, but when executing the task it runs with an administrator account.

Comment: Please **share more details about how you made that happen** - scheduled tasks don't magically start running under different accounts.

Comment: We are a company, each has its own user. I created the task with my own user, but when I run it I use an administrator user. So the task is being executed with the highest privileged account possible.

Answer (score -1):

By adding Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force at the beginning of the script, temporarily change the PowerShell execution policy.

Wrap your scripts with a PowerShell command to run as an administrator:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process 
PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 
\"your_script_path.ps1\"' -Verb RunAs}"
```

These methods will help you overcome permission access problems.

Comment: I put the "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force"
and when I run it in PowerShell ISE as an administrator it works and edits the hosts file.
But when I run it through the task scheduler it cannot edit the hosts file.

Comment: Action:
program/script:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional):
-File "C:\Serviço Windows.ps1"


He runs the program, which appears in the background, but is unable to edit the hosts file.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Note that you cannot perform on-demand elevation from a scheduled task, unless it happens to run interactively.

Comment: I'm passing an argument in the task: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Serviço Windows.ps1" and also within the script an execution policy code "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force" And even so it doesn't can edit the hosts file.